# Overwrite variable on txt file with form submit

Tags: php, forms, file, form-submit, increment

what im trying to do is when the user clicks on increment button $var which is stored in  File.txt becomes $var+10 here's what i got:

first.php code :

```
 <?php $myFile = "File.txt";
 $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
 $theData = fread($fh, 5);
 fclose($fh);

 ?>
```

and here's the main page code :

```
 <?php  

       include 'first.php';

       $var = $theData + 10;

  $myFile = "File.txt";
   $thetext=$_POST['sometext'];
   writemyfile($myFile,$thetext,"w");


  function readmyfile($thefile)
  { 
  $myfile=fopen($thefile,"r");
  $x = fread($myfile, filesize($thefile));
  fclose($myfile);
  return $x;
    }

  function writemyfile($thefilename,$data,$mode)    
  {
  $myfile=fopen($thefilename,$mode);
  fwrite($myfile,$data);
  fclose($myfile);
  } 

  ?>
      <html>
      <head>
      <title>Example of a form</title></head>
      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $php_self ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="sometext" value="<?php echo $var ?>" >
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="increment">
      </form>

      </html>
```

the problem is everytime i refresh the main page without clicking the increment button the value on File.txt disepears.

Comment: have your writemyfile method have some error checking to make sure that there is actually a value there. If thetext is null, as it maybe in the case of refreshing a page with no POST values, then it'll open the file as write, and try to write null into it.

Comment: You write to file every time mainpage.php is processed, even if `$_POST` is empty (page refresh without form being sent). Check `$_POST` for being non-empty before writing to that file.

Comment: here's what i came up with but still not working:       $myFile = "File.txt";
 $thetext=$_POST['sometext'];
        if ($_POST['sometext'] = NULL){
  $thetext = -1;
  
} else {
 writemyfile($myFile,$thetext,"w");};